# Ignore hidden columns in SUM(x:y), like AGGREGATE can ignore hidden rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I know there is a similar answer here: 
[Ignoring a hidden column in an excel sum formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589839/ignoring-a-hidden-column-in-an-excel-sum-formula)

...and it's a good one, but it isn't ideal for me. I really just need a simple function I can apply dynamically.

Is there a way to do this in a similar way to the `AGGREGATE` function?
`AGGREGATE` almost works for me, except it annoyingly ignores hidden rows but not columns!

For example:

I have a worksheet with values in `A5:A10`.

If I set the formula of `A11` to `=SUM(A5:A10)` I get the expected amount, whether columns are hidden or not.

If I use `=AGGREGATE(9,5,A5:A10)` the results are the same, although if I did this across rows rather than columns the hidden rows would be ignored in the calculation.

Is there a simple way to do this or is the only way to check the width of each column, as in the answer provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add one line above/below the header and fill it with just 0 or 1, then horizontally sum each line using an array formula, e.g.

```
    A           B   C   D   E   F
1   Selector    1   1   0   0   
2   Data        1   2   3   4   3
```

Formula in F2: `{=SUM(B2:E2*B$1:E$1)}` (enter without curly brackets, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to save). You then can copy the formula down your list like normal.

Comment: Oops ... sorry was too fast

Comment: @bukko different attempt using data selectors

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the columns and only add values in columns that are not hidden.

It'll look like this:

```
Dim yourRow As Integer
Dim rowSum As Integer
yourRow = X
rowSum = 0

For i = 1 to NumberOfColumns

If Sheets(1).Columns(i).Hidden = False Then

rowSum = rowSum + Sheets(1).Cells(yourRow, i)

Next i
```