# Sum only visible cells in one ROW (not column)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, aggregate, subtotal

I have a row and I want to sum only visible cells, i know if it's a column I can use subtotal (109,range), but this one doesn't seem to work for cells in one row. Anyone knows how to sum only visible cells in a row?

[Please click here for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFHAe.png)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a VBA solution is okay, this will work:

```
Function sumVisible(rng As Range) As Double
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In rng
    If cel.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
        sumVisible = sumVisible + cel.Value
    End If
Next cel
End Function
```

Pretty straightforward - just checks if a cell in your range has a hidden column, if it's visible, sum it.

`=sumVisible(D2:M2)` is how you'd use it.

Comment: I do think it a little odd that the Excel folks would include a method (`SUBTOTAL()`) for summing hidden rows, but not one for hidden columns. I wonder why.

Comment: yep, remove duplicates has the same problem

Answer (score 2):

You can check the width of the cell.

```
=IF(CELL("width",A1)=0,"hidden","open")
```

you can then sum your cells as need it using IF and CELL

```
=IF(CELL("width",A1)=0,0,A1)
```

more info below:
[Ignoring a hidden column in an excel sum formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589839/ignoring-a-hidden-column-in-an-excel-sum-formula)

Comment: Using this method, OP would have to create another group of data, then sum that, right?  Of would there be a way to throw this into an array formula?

Comment: @BruceWayne no `CELL` will not work in arrays.  It can only be used one cell at a time.  so to use this would require a helper row.

Comment: Thank you, I actually found someway to go around it but I tried your formula. It works but the problem is, it's good for one time sum but if I changed the width of the cell i need to manually refresh it. What I am trying to do is I have a vba to automatically hide the columns I don't want and I hope the sum can change when I change the columns that have been hidden.

Comment: @ScottCraner Actually we can use CELL with arrays, with a little coercion.

Comment: It should be pointed out to the OP that this solution is not guaranteed to consider hidden columns only. Any column with a width of less than 0.5 will also be considered as equal to 0 in this construction.

Comment: @XORLX Out of curiosity, how?

Comment: @ScottCraner Posted as answer - thought might be more useful there than as a comment

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a single worksheet formula alone, provided that none of the columns which remain unhidden will have a width of less than or equal to 0.5 (which, in practice, would be so narrow as to be virtually hidden in any case).

Assuming a range of `A1:E1`

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(CELL("width",OFFSET(A1,,N(INDEX(COLUMN(A1:E1)-MIN(COLUMN(A1:E1)),,))))>0),A1:E1)`

Unfortunately this formula will not update automatically as changes regarding hiding/unhiding columns within the range are made. As such, it will be necessary to 'recommit' it each time you make changes in that respect; one way to do this is via going into the formula as if to edit it and then recommitting by pressing ENTER.

Perhaps of interest [is this post](https://excelxor.com/2014/11/04/coercing-array-returns-from-cse-resistant-formulas/).

Regards

Comment: That is an awful lot of work around. But I bow to your expertise.

Comment: :-) I never said it was a simple solution!